# Handle invalid json when submitted to an express server

Tags: javascript, express, body-parser

What is the best way to catch invalid JSON here?

When I `POST`

```
{
  "name": "rob
}
```

to `/user`, I get the stacktrace below returned as a response, how could I catch this on all endpoints to provide a more custom error?

Assuming a `try .. catch` is not appropriate around all routes, is there a cleaner way?

`app.js`

```
app.route('/user/:id')
  .get(function(req, res) {
    user.get(req, res);
  });
app.route('/user')
  .post(bodyParser.json(), function(req, res) {
    user.add(req, res);
  });
app.route('/user')
  .put(bodyParser.json(), function(req, res) {
    user.update(req, res);
  });
app.route('/post/:id')
  .get(function(req, res) {
    post.get(req, res);
  });
```

Error thrown when submitting invalid `JSON` ..

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected string
  Object.parse (native)
  parse (/home/rob/git/project/service/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:88:17)
  /home/rob/git/project/service/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:116:18
  invokeCallback (/home/rob/git/project/service/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:262:16)
  done (/home/rob/git/project/service/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:251:7)
  IncomingMessage.onEnd (/home/rob/git/project/service/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:307:7)
  IncomingMessage.&lt;anonymous&gt; (/home/rob/git/project/service/node_modules/dependency-project/node_modules/log4js-client/node_modules/request-context/node_modules/continuation-local-storage/context.js:84:17)
  emitNone (events.js:67:13)
  IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
  IncomingMessage.emitted [as emit] (/home/rob/git/project/service/node_modules/dependency-project/node_modules/log4js-client/node_modules/request-context/node_modules/continuation-local-storage/node_modules/emitter-listener/listener.js:122:21)
  endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:913:12)
  /home/rob/git/project/service/node_modules/request-context/node_modules/continuation-local-storage/node_modules/async-listener/glue.js:188:31
  nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
  process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)
```

Comment: Why not to catch the error on client side?

Comment: this is a REST based microservice, being invoked by another microservice. Theres no UI

Comment: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/blob/master/lib/types/json.js
in the 88th line the JSON.parse function used only one time in the source script.
Maybe to catch the error on that would resolve the issue?